# using HtmlWeb causes HttpWebRequest to timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

So I've got a situation where I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` to load web pages in order to scrape the Document contents.  I have a number of URLs that I need to load and a few of them require gzip encoding so I catch the exception thrown by `HtmlWeb.load()`, check that it's a gzip encoding issue, and then process the page load with `HttpWebRequest`.  However this allows the first time through with `HttpWebRequest` to be successful, but any other attemp with `HttpWebRequest` will timeout.

Here's a cleaned up version of the code:

```
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            try
            {
                doc = web.Load(uri);

                Console.WriteLine("htmlweb and htmldocument success");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("htmlweb and htmldocument not successful");
                if (ae.Message.Contains("\'gzip\'"))
                {
                    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                    try
                    {
                        req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
                        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                        req.Method = "GET";
                        //req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))";
                        string source;
                        req.KeepAlive = false;
                        //req.Timeout = 100000;

                        // On the second iteration we never get beyond this line
                        using (WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
                        {
                            using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webResponse as HttpWebResponse)
                            {
                                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                                {
                                    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        req.Abort();
                        Console.WriteLine("httpwebresponse successfull");
                    }
                    catch (WebException we)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("httpwebresponse not successful");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there some cleanup that I'm needing to do? or is there something I'm forgetting?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I will have to load via WebRequest first, instead of HtmlWeb. then inspect the response header for gzip, and decompress as needed each time.

```
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            //req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
            //req.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            //req.Method = "GET";
            string source = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webResponse as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        StreamReader reader;
                        if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                        {
                            reader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
                        }
                        else if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                        {
                            reader = new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                        }
                        source = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

            req.Abort();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                //received a 404 Error - apparently one of my links is now dead...
            }
```